# Canonical shop - Bootable USB stick - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, 16.04, live-usb, canonical

I can't find information about the size in GB for the [bootable USB stick](https://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1206) that Canonical is selling. Do they sell them in 2, 4, or 8 GB in size?

Has anyone already purchased it to confirm?

Comment: Why does it matter? It is just an install disk. It has just enough space for the install files! It may be a write-once disk (because of cheaper costs), really shouldn't consider it for every day use.

Comment: Canonical Store has since updated [the product page](https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) and is no longer selling bootable USB/CDs.

Answer (score 3):

I took the old fashioned approach of emailing the store via its contact form and the definitive answer is that the stick is 8GB. I quote the email below, with my own email address edited out:

```
Date: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 10:11:56 +0100
From: eStore Support <estoresupport@merchandisemania.co.uk>
To: 'AndrewStrong' <andrew.xxxxxx@xxx.com>
Subject: RE: [Canonical] Enquiry from Canonical Store
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0

Good Morning

The capacity of the stick is 8GB

Regards

Support

-----Original Message-----
From: AndrewStrong [mailto:andrew.xxxxx@xxxx.com]
Sent: 17 June 2016 21:37
To: Merchandise Mania
Subject: [Canonical] Enquiry from Canonical Store

A new enquiry has been made on the Canonical Store.

Name: AndrewStrong
E-mail: andrew.xxxxx@xxxx.com
Enquiry Type: Sizes

Message:
Hi,

Concerning:

The \'Bootable USB stick\' SKU code: UBN30056-M

Can you tell me what is the capacity of the stick?

Thanks,

Andrew Strong
```

Note by the way that the Canonical Store Support uses Microsoft Outlook 14.0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Canonical Store has since added more information for Bootable USB stick, following the query made by @andrew.46. See the product page snapshots comparison in screenshot below.

[image: Product page snapshot compared]

The additional info section now writes:

```
Capacity: 8GB USB 2.0

SKU code: UBN30056-M
```

Prior to the update, the [old snapshot dated June 6, 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160606115938/http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1206) is the only snapshot saved by the Internet Archive Wayback Machine. I consider myself lucky for noticing and posting this answer.